# Can I execute a Google App scripts via Sheets URL?

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Can't get OAuth to work, so I settled for a public spreadsheet, able to download data via URL (range/value). Struggling to get upload data via JSON embedded in POST, then I thought I saw some other approach: Is it somehow possible to write an app script that writes a value to cell and embed that data in the URL together with the request to execute the app script ?

Basically, download data via GET and upload data via GET, sounds crazy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You just need a function called doGet and then you can deploy the script as a web app. Here is an example.

```
function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e, null, 2));
}
```

If you then open the web app url with some parameters added to it e.g. `https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec?a=3&b=4` you should see that those parameters are now contained in e so your script can just read them and add them to your spreadsheet.

Comment: sorry, I finally got Oauth working, so I didn't have to use the AppScript 'backdoor', but it looks like that would have been the way to go, so thanks